# How to shade outside of a rectangle inside another rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

please help me to draw this diagram.

[image]

I am mostly stuck with the shading part. Please help.

Comment: Fill the large one, u fill the inner one (which is just drawing a white area) then redraw the edges of each rectangle

Comment: Use `even odd rule`, e.g. `\draw[fill=blue,even odd rule] (-3,-3)  rectangle ++ (6,6)
(-2,-2)  rectangle ++ (4,4);`.

Comment: @daleif, Ah! What a fool I was! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, this also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer `even odd rule` because it avoids overpainting something in white. So such figures can be put on top of nontrivial backgrounds.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=3;b=2;}]
 \draw[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
 (a,-a) node[right]{$X$}  rectangle ++ (-2*a,2*a) node[above]{$Y$}
 (b,-b)   rectangle ++ (-2*b,2*b) ;
 \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={calligraphic brace,raise=0.3ex}]
  \draw[decorate]  (b,-a) -- (-b,-a) node[midway,below=0.5ex]{$A$}; 
  \draw[decorate]  (-a,-b) -- (-a,b) node[midway,left=0.5ex]{$B$}; 
  \path (0,a/2+b/2) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=right:{$(x_0,y_0)$}]{};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain shortly this line `\draw[fill=blue,even odd rule] 
 (a,-a) node[right]{$X$}  rectangle ++ (-2*a,2*a) node[above]{$Y$}
 (b,-b)   rectangle ++ (-2*b,2*b) ;` I am getting confused at where to put which parameter?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul It draws both rectangles but fills only the area between them. `even odd rule` is explained on p. 179 of pgfmanual v3.1.5